# how to fix error: cannot access zzbej class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbej not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my android app, I'm trying to get the location of the user, I can't run my app on the emulator because of the failed build

I've tried 
Clean project - Rebuild project - sync project with Gradle files - sync with file system -Invalidate caches

```
  private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
```

```
  private void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
    }
```

error is:

```
error: cannot access zzbej
class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbej not found
```

Gradle (app level):

```
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.2'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.2'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.2' 
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.8'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
```

Gradle (project level):

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

            configurations.matching { it.name == '_internal_aapt2_binary' }.all { config ->
                config.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                    details.useVersion("3.5.0-alpha03-5252756")
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    }
}
```

Everything should be ok but the error keeps occurring at the second line of the createLocationRequest fun whatever was it.

Comment: what dependencies are you pulling? show your gradle files

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski done

Comment: @rakesd231 do you connect to services before making request?

Comment: @rakesd231 why do you put gradle-tools and google-services twice with two different versions?

Comment: @BorisRuzanov yes I did connect to services, it's required for my implementations

Comment: @rakesd231 the problem is in dependencies I would recommend remove duplication of the dependencies first and after that put correct versions. After that it suppose to work